# Make a file executable with Ansible, then make Ansible execute it

Tags: ansible, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm currently writing a playbook / role where I install a GitLab Runner on a server. Here is [the link](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-manually.html) to the instructions I'm following.

So, the steps would look as follow:

1. Download the `gitlab-runner`binary, put in in `/usr/local/bin/`, then use `chmod +x` to allow it to be executed.
2. Create a "gitlab-runner" user, create him a personal directory, and decide that he will use `/bin/bash` if he wants to run a command
3. Install the service and specify which user, and which home directory will be used.
4. (and 5.) Run the service, and register it (I'm not here yet)

So, here are the things: When I log to the remote host, via Ansible or not, I can't log directly as root. My user, 'ansible', has sudo privileges, but the thing is that it looks that he can't run the `gitlab-runner` command, because it's not found (even though I chmod'd +x the file when I copied it)

When I logged myself onto the remote server as 'ansible', the command wasn't found, but when I tried to run it with sudo, it returned me:

> Fatal: please run the command as root

I'm not familiar with Ansible yet, but this is what I got:

```
- name: copy gitlab-runner binary from local to remote host(s)
  copy:
    src: gitlab-runner
    dest: /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner
    mode: +x
  register: binary

- name: Create a gitlab-runner user
  user:
    name: 'gitlab-runner'
    comment: 'GitLab Runner'
    create_home: yes
    shell: /bin/bash

- name: Install gitlab-runner
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  shell: gitlab-runner install --user=gitlab-runner --working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

I used to run the command with the `command` service, but it returned me stranges things such as `no such file or directory`. Now it returns `command not found`, which is slightly better.

First question: Am I doing the copy right? I mean, the copy itselfs runs smoothly, but am I doing it right by setting `mode: +x` in it, or should I add the mode after the copy?

Second question: What would be the correct way to become root in my situation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use path to gitlab-runner and use command module, there is no need for shell.

```
command: /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner ...
```

> First question: Am I doing the copy right?

Take a look at *dest: /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner*

> Second question: What would be the correct way to become root in my situation?

The one that you use. You might want check on your own

```
- name: Who am I ?                                                                       
  become: yes                                                                            
  become_user: root                                                                      
  command: whoami                                                                        
  register: result                                                                       
- debug: var=result.stdout
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, when I switch to root, don't I need to give Ansible the root password? It's not the same than the one I used for `ansible_become_password`

Comment: Do you? What's the output running *- name: Who am I* ?

Comment: It... works, I mean, I get "root" as a response (that makes me remind to validate your response), but... how ? Why don't I need to specify my root password when I need it as a daily basis?

Comment: You stated in the question: "My user, 'ansible', has sudo privileges".

Comment: ...Oh, I get it.

Thanks!